# How to populate Kendo.ComboBox with ajax?

Tags: ajax, telerik-mvc, kendo-combobox, editortemplates

I have a `Kendo.ComboBox` defined in the `Editor Template`.

This template is referenced in the index page when Kendo.Grid is populated:

```
co.Bound(c => c.Name).Title("Property Name").EditorTemplateName("_MyEditor");
```

This is the ComboBox:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
          .Name("ReportProperty")
          .DataTextField("PropertyName")
          .DataValueField("ReportPropertyID")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "idCB" })
)
```

There is an Event that fires in which I would like to use an Ajax call to populate this Kendo.ComboBox.

I do not wamt to use `.DataSource` with Action call for that, I tried and it did not work in my case, so I want to use`Ajax` on a specific event

What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

try as below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
          .Name("ReportProperty")
          .DataTextField("PropertyName")
          .DataValueField("ReportPropertyID")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "idCB" })
          .DataSource(source => {
             source.Read(read =>
             {
                 read.Action("Action", "Controller");
             })
      })
)
```